# what does the "a" in chattr +ia do?

Tags: linux, filesystems, permissions, xattr

what does the `a` in `chattr +ia <filename>` do? and why would you add the `a` in combination with the `i`? *note: I know the `i` is for immutable*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
>   The  letters  `acdeijstuADST'  select the new attributes for the files:
>   append only (a), compressed  (c),  no  dump  (d),  extent  format  (e),
>   immutable (i), data journalling (j), secure deletion (s), no tail-merg‐
>   ing (t), undeletable (u), no atime updates (A),  synchronous  directory
>   updates  (D),  synchronous  updates (S), and top of directory hierarchy
>   (T).
> ```
>
> from the [manpage for `chattr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr)

Files with this flag will fail to be opened for writing. This also blocks certain potentially destructive system calls such as [`truncate()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate) or [`unlink()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink).

```
$ touch foo
$ chattr +a foo
$ python
> file("foo", "w") #attempt to open for writing
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'foo'
> quit()
$ truncate foo --size 0
truncate: cannot open `foo' for writing: Operation not permitted
$ echo "Appending works fine." >> foo
$ cat foo
Appending works fine.
$ rm foo
rm: cannot remove `foo': Operation not permitted
$ chattr -a foo
$ rm foo
```

This option is designed for log files.

Comment: but why would you do immutable and append only? immutable kind of prevents any writing... (we do this at work when locking sites for TOS violations and I don't understand why the a)

Comment: @xeno that's a good question. At first analysis +a adds nothing that +i doesn't do (except paranoia); I'd check  the source code of your kernel to be extra sure.

Comment: @xenoterracide: I don't see much point. It could be belt and braces, in case someone removes the `i` (but someone who wants to and knows how do remove the immutable attribute would know about the append-only attribute anyway).

Comment: "belt and braces" in English means "belt and suspenders" in American for our international readers.